# ArcGIS Operation Dashboard

Tags: sql-server, arcgis-online, vb, operations-dashboard

I am working on ArcGIS operation Dashboard. There is an widget on the top left corner “ Model Manager”. Here the Model manager will read the data from ForecastStage_MPT and ForecastTimePT database tables. These 2 database tables are in MS SQL server database. The data in these 2 tables are populated from NOAA. A script has been developed which will take the data from the NOAA website and populate the ForecastStage_MPT and ForecastTimePT database tables. My task is to read the data from the database tables into the ArcGIS operation dashboard model manager widget automatically. Do you have any idea how to read the MS SQL server database tables into the model manager widget? I am sending you 3 attachments and see if you can give me some directions.

[image: ArcGIS Operation Dashboard]

[image: ForecastStage_MPT]

[image: ForecastTimePT]

Comment: yes , you can upload your sql data to your layer (feature service), just use post rest api call for (appluedits or add feature) inside windows service.

Comment: or use ArcGIS Server to host the tables as a service, should sync the edits ran by your script

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can upload your sql data to your layer (feature service), just use post rest api call for (appluedits or add feature) inside windows service.

Here is the fellow :

1. export your sql data to csv files .
2. import csv files to your arcgis online account.
3. now you have a layer or feature service contains your sql data , make your layer editable.
4. you can updates layers content by using API method like apllyedits and add features.